# Spring MVC: In controller all handler methods need same path variable. shortcut?

Tags: spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC Controller, almost all handler methods need to access the same path variable. Something like this:

```
@GetMapping(...)
public String handler1( @PathVariable Long var,.. ) {
    // do some stuff with var
}


@GetMapping(...)
public String handler2( @PathVariable Long var,.. ) {
    // do some stuff with var
}
```

I am aware of this (adding var to the model as a property in every request)

```
@ModelAttribute("var")
public Long getVar( @PathVariable Long var ) {
    return var
}
```

However, I "just" need var in the handler and not in the view-model! Is there any SPRINGISH way to shortcut the access in my handlers to var?